# Is the superhero X-23's name a shout out to an Asimov story?

Tags: marvel, x-men, reference, the-last-question

I was reading Isaac Asimov's story [“The Last Question”](https://www.multivax.com/last_question.html) for the upteenth time, but this time I noticed something: the planet the family of colonists are going to is called X-23.

Well, maybe it's just a coincidence, but I wouldn't be surprised if [Craig Kyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_Kyle), X-23 creator, took the character's name from that story. Is there any evidence backing up that hypothesis?

Comment: I've twitted at Craig. Hopefully he can enlighten us.

Comment: In-universe she's the 23rd iteration of a genetic experiment. Note that X-18, X-19, X-20, X-21, X-22 and X-24 all existed within the Marvel universe prior to her creation. Mostly robots.

Comment: I've also heard it as an allusion to the number of human chromosomes, with her status as an opposite sex clone involving them stabilizing her by mirroring the X chromosome.

Comment: @Valorum cool! Can you give us a link to the tweet?

Comment: https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1313202654898720769

Comment: @Valorum Is that right? It's been a while since I was actively reading (so I'm only vaguely aware of this character at all) but since the original 'Weapon X' was the 10th iteration ('X' being the roman numeral for '10'), how does that track? Weapon 10-23?

Comment: @AlexM - https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-22_(Earth-616)

Comment: @Valorum interesting stuff (I had no idea they were writing new books to retcon the origins of _Machine Man_ of all characters) but not at all clear how or if that's related to X-23 or the Weapon X program?

Comment: @AlexM - It's unrelated, but you can't just go around creating characters that have the same name as other characters.

Comment: @AlexM Weapon X was the tenth iteration of the Weapon Plus program, but became an offshoot/splinter of the Weapon Plus program and carried on in its own right. Each iteration of Weapon Plus was a program of experiments and often produced or experimented on more than one individual. https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_Plus